# Spring Apache Kafka onFailure Callback of KafkaTemplate not fired on connection error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm experimenting a lot with Apache Kafka in a Spring Boot App at the moment.

My current goal is to write a REST endpoint that takes in some message payload, which will use a KafkaTemplate to send the data to my local Kafka running on port 9092.

This is my producer config:

```java
@Bean
public Map<String,Object> producerConfig() {

    // config settings for creating producers
    Map<String,Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,this.bootstrapServers);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG,5000);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,4000);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,0);

    return configProps;

}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String,String> producerFactory() {
    // creates a kafka producer
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
}

@Bean("kafkaTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate(){
    // template which abstracts sending data to kafka
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

My rest endpoint forwards to a service, the service looks like this:

```java
  @Service
    public class KafkaSenderService {

        @Qualifier("kafkaTemplate")
        private final KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;

        @Autowired
        public KafkaSenderService(KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate) {
            this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        }

        public void sendMessageWithCallback(String message, String topicName) {

            // possibility to add callbacks to define what shall happen in success/ error case
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);

            future.addCallback(new KafkaSendCallback<String, String>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(KafkaProducerException ex) {
                    logger.warn("Message could not be delivered. " + ex.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                    logger.info("Your message was delivered with following offset: " + result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
                }
            });

        }
}
```

The thing now is: I'm expecting the "onFailure()" method to get called when the message could not be sent. But this seems not to work. When I change the bootstrapServers variable in the producer config to localhost:9091 (which is the wrong port, so there should be no connection possible), the producer tries to connect to the broker. It will do several connection attempts, and after 5 seconds, a TimeOutException will occur. But the "onFailure() method won't get called. Is there a way to achieve that the "onFailure()" method can get called event if the connection cannot be established?

And by the way, I set the retries count to zero, but the prodcuer still does a second connection attempt after the first one. This is the log output:

EDIT: it seems like the Kafke producer/ KafkaTemplate goes into an infinite loop when the broker is not available. Is that really the intended behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question answered inside the discussion on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2250# for anyone else stumbling across this thread. In short, `kafkaTemplate.getProducerFactory().reset();`does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The `KafkaTemplate` does really nothing fancy about connection and publishing. Everything is delegated to the `KafkaProducer`. What you describe here would happen exactly even if you'd use just plain Kafka Client.

See `KafkaProducer.send()` JavaDocs:

```
 * @throws TimeoutException If the record could not be appended to the send buffer due to memory unavailable
 *                          or missing metadata within {@code max.block.ms}.
```

Which happens by the blocking logic in that producer:

```
/**
 * Wait for cluster metadata including partitions for the given topic to be available.
 * @param topic The topic we want metadata for
 * @param partition A specific partition expected to exist in metadata, or null if there's no preference
 * @param nowMs The current time in ms
 * @param maxWaitMs The maximum time in ms for waiting on the metadata
 * @return The cluster containing topic metadata and the amount of time we waited in ms
 * @throws TimeoutException if metadata could not be refreshed within {@code max.block.ms}
 * @throws KafkaException for all Kafka-related exceptions, including the case where this method is called after producer close
 */
private ClusterAndWaitTime waitOnMetadata(String topic, Integer partition, long nowMs, long maxWaitMs) throws InterruptedException {
```

Unfortunately this is not explained in the `send()` JavaDocs which claims to be fully asynchronous, but apparently it is not. At least in this metadata part which has to be available before we enqueue the record for publishing.

That's what we cannot control and it is not reflected on the returned `Future`:

```
        try {
            clusterAndWaitTime = waitOnMetadata(record.topic(), record.partition(), nowMs, maxBlockTimeMs);
        } catch (KafkaException e) {
            if (metadata.isClosed())
                throw new KafkaException("Producer closed while send in progress", e);
            throw e;
        }
```

See more info in Apache Kafka docs how to adjust the `KafkaProducer` for this matter: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theproducer

Comment: Thanks for cour comment. I had a look into the code. The "waitOnMetadata()" method can throw a timeout exception if it could not fetch the metadata for a given topic. This exception is also passed to the caller of the doSend method inside the KafkaProdcuer. So why does the KafkaTemplate not react properly to this Timeout Exception,  tells the prodcuer to stop the sending process and also lets the future complete?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The exception for that `waitOnMetadata()` is thrown from the `doSend()` far before that `Future` is formed and returned. The producer is just blocked at this point until metadata is returned. There is no async hand off yet. A different reaction is just not possible for this architecture of Kafka Producer.

Comment: I get your point, but I actually don't understand why it is not possible to watch for the TimeoutException. The KafkaTemplate's `doSend` method calls the `send()` method of the KafkaProducer. This will invoke it's own `doSend()` method. In this `doSend()` method, the `waitOnMetadata()` method is called, which will throw the TimeOutException. This exception is forwareded to the caller of the `doSend()` method (if metadata.isClosed()) [...] throw e). I don't understand why there is no possiblity to watch for the thrown TimeoutException in the KafkaTemplate?

Comment: I haven't implemented any methods using `Future` myself, but do you mean that the `TimeoutException` can only be fetched when `future.get()` is called? Is this the only way to watch for the exception? Is it not possible to wrap that  `Future<RecordMetadata> sendFuture = producer.send(producerRecord, buildCallback(producerRecord, producer, future, sample));` (inside KafkaTemplates doSend method) with a try ... catch and listen for the TimeoutException? I thought this is possible because the exception is thrown before any future is returned.

Comment: Okay, I think I found it. The TimeoutException is part of the future, as it is caught in the surrounding try ... catch inside the `doSend()` of the KafkaProducer and this `FutureFailure` is returned. I just realized that the TimeOutException is also an ApiException. 

But my question remains: Why does the KafkaTemplate not for example close the producer when there is a failure in the sending process? The producer is gonna starve to death if it will try to connect to an unavailable Kafka Cluster.