# KafkaTemplate producer send callback onFailure not called on Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

So I was testing the resiliency of my producer, I have this object that I want to send to kafka (in json format), then depending on the result, it will update my database. The onSuccess callback works perfectly, but the onFailure does not trigger at all, making me unable to do what I intended in case of send failure, cant even test it.

I tried sending my object to a non existing topic, all I got are some error logs and I know it has exception since the LoggingProducerListener says so. I checked the code of KafkaTemplate, it should have registered the error as it is intended before notifying the LoggingProducerListener. Heres the code and the log.

```
final ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendResultListenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, myEntityInJson);
            sendResultListenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                    myEntity.setIsSentToKafka(true);
                    myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
                    log.info(": Successfully sent to kafka.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                    myEntity.setIsSentToKafka(false);
                    myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
                    log.error(" Sending to kafka failed!", ex);
                }

            });
```

LOGS

```
2022-05-26 18:36:45,my-service,,,, WARN,12848,kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 8 : {first_topic3=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
2022-05-26 18:36:54,my-service,554bb0161acb9fc6,ced0246162fbd1a4,,ERROR,12848,pool-4-thread-1,LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{"id":10565,.....' to topic first_topic3:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic first_topic3 not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
2022-05-26 18:36:55,my-service,,,, WARN,12848,kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : {first_topic3=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

Comment: There's no topic to send to, so the error is not happening _after the send_. The onFailure is never reached in this case. Regarding your code, 2PC isn't really recommended because you aren't guaranteed data atomically in either location; you should use something like Kafka Connect or a consumer after the data is in Kafka to write to a Repository/Database

Comment: I currently don't have the permission to consume the message.

Answer (score 2):

That's how `KafkaProducer` works. It does fetch metadata in a *sync*, blocking manner and throws an exception back to the caller immediately. The `onFailure()` is called in *async* manner only if connection is established with the broker an the record is placed to a buffer. So, you need to use `try..catch` around that `kafkaTemplate.send()` to handle that kind of `Error while fetching metadata` problems.

See for more info in this discussion: [Spring Apache Kafka onFailure Callback of KafkaTemplate not fired on connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055135/spring-apache-kafka-onfailure-callback-of-kafkatemplate-not-fired-on-connection)

Comment: Understood, thanks. However the one in this udemy course "Apache Kafka for Developers using Spring Boot[LatestEdition]" has the onfailure called on connection error, in my code it does not do that, same as the topic not found error

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to hear as an answer to your argument. You want to make it working as it is explained in that course? Then it is not possible as we both have just confirmed: it just doesn't work that way. Perhaps that course was made long time ago when `KafkaProducer` did the error handling that way. It is not at the moment.